# What's the difference between system testing and release testing?

Tags: terminology, system-testing

I was going through the types of software testing...Can anyone tell me what exactly are the differences between system testing and release testing?

Comment: Where did you encounter those terms?

Comment: Software Engineering - Ian Somerville

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this in Ian Somerville's book (9th edition, section 8.3):

> There are two important distinctions between release testing and
>   system testing during the development process:
>
> 1. A separate team that has not been involved in the system development should be responsible for release testing.
> 2. System testing by the development team should focus on discovering bugs in the system (defect testing). The objective of release testing
>      is to check that the system meets its requirements and is good enough
>      for external use (validation testing).

Answer (score 1):

**System Testing**

System testing of software or hardware is testing conducted on a
complete, integrated system to evaluate the system's compliance with its particular needs.

System testing falls within the scope of black-box testing, and as such should require no idea of the inner design of the code or logic.

[image]

**Release Testing**

Each release undergoes a series of automated and manual testing to ensure the quality of the finished product. In order to maximize our ability to find bugs before users do, we conduct a battery of tests designed to exercise as much functionality as possible.

These tests emphasize variety over raw quantity, however, with each feature release requiring approximately a week of round-the-clock testing.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of Ian Somerville's definition there's a more obvious difference, "system" and "release" refers to different things.

System refers to the content of the activity, you can test a unit and then call it unit test, modules or subsystems then call it integration tests, or a whole system and then call it system test.

Release refers to the timing of the activity, towards a release. A release test can be either at the unit level, module or system and still be called release test.